# Callback after emit()

Tags: angular, angular-event-emitter

I have this Parent Component:

```
export class VdsPickerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() onSelect: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  select(value) {
    this.onSelect.emit(value);
    console.log("should run second");
  }
}
```

and this child Component

```
export class AppPickerComponent implements OnInit {
  select(value) {
    this.api.getApplication(value.id).subscribe(res => {
      console.log("should run first");
      this.context.currentApplication = res;
    });
  }
}
```

And this is the html of the AppPickerComponent

```
<vds-picker [(value)]="this.context.currentApplication"
            [(currentValue)]="this.currentApplication"
            description="description"
            placeholder="Choisir une application..."
            [editTemplate]="appedit"
            [readonly]="readonly"
            [showActions]="showActions"
            [results]="results"
            (onFilter)="filter($event)"
            (onSelect)="select($event)"
            (onCreate)="create($event)"
            (onUpdate)="update($event)"
            (onSubmit)="submit($event)"
            (onOpShow)="onOpShow($event)">
    <ng-template #appedit>
        <div id="opappadd">
            <div><input #appcode type="text" style="width: 150px;" pInputText [(ngModel)]="this.currentApplication.code" placeholder="Code" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" [disabled]="this.currentApplication.id" /></div>
            <div><input #appdesc type="text" style="width: 400px;" pInputText [(ngModel)]="this.currentApplication.description" placeholder="Description" /></div>
            <div><p-checkbox #thirdparty binary="true" [(ngModel)]="this.currentApplication.isThirdPartyApp" label="Application tierce"></p-checkbox></div>
            <div><input type="text" style="width: 400px;" pInputText [(ngModel)]="this.currentApplication.thirdPartyGetEndpoint" placeholder="Uri vers le endpoint GET pour les autorisations" [disabled]="!thirdparty.checked" /></div>
            <div><input type="text" style="width: 400px;" pInputText [(ngModel)]="this.currentApplication.thirdPartyPostEndpoint" placeholder="Uri vers le endpoint POST pour les autorisations" [disabled]="!thirdparty.checked" /></div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</vds-picker>
```

Now, I would like to have a callback on the emit(), so that once my event is finished (and successful), I can do some additional work in the parent Component.

How can I make the above code log in the console :

```
should run first
should run second
```

EDIT:

Giving a more concrete example of what I aim to achieve. So I will have an `@Output() onSubmit` I want to provide a function that will do the job to call the backend and handle the success/errors. The submit form is in an overlayPanel and once the backend call is a success, I want to hide the panel. If there were validation errors, I don't want to hide the panel and I want to show an error message inside the panel. I don't want the user to think about hiding the panel if it's a success, the component should handle that itself.

Comment: Are you sure you have it the right way? That `VdsPickerComponent` is the parent component and `AppPickerComponent ` is the child component? Please show your template (html). Because I don't think the parent component outputs to the child component.

Comment: I updated my question. I might not have the parent/child the good way around, haha